# why casper click() doesnot work

Tags: click, casperjs

I have a problem on casper's click() function 
the click() function works properly with an anchor like `<a class="a1" href="javascript:void(0)">NEXT PAGE</a>`
but it will not work if an element binds events from an external config.js like this `<span next-value="2000">next</span>` ，will call `<script src="http://.../config.js" type="text/javascript">` in html.
how should I deal with this.

Comment: It works just as with the anchor element. Please register to the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors. If bind is an issue, you need a [shim](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522#issuecomment-39248521).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should include the config.js if you aren't already doing that. [API](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#index-1)